# autoware_auto_launch not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am checkout to setup AVP demo on a new machine. After installing docker/ade I followed the instructions here:
https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/avpdemo.html

When I try to launch autoware_auto_visualization.launch.py I get the following error:

ros2 launch autoware_auto_launch autoware_auto_visualization.launch.py
Package 'autoware_auto_launch' not found: "package 'autoware_auto_launch' not found, searching: ['/opt/AutowareAuto', '/opt/ros/foxy']"

I cannot find the package autoware_auto_launch package anywhere in the repository. Am I missing something?

full logs here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2102902

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375760/autoware_auto_launch-not-found/) by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2021-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on 2021-04-09**:
Eventually I managed ti have it working properly.
For some unknown reason, the file was missing in /opt/AutowareAuto/. I couldn't find it either in my src directory. Maybe I was using an old autoware branch? (but as far as know I am only moving between 1.0.0 and master)

**Comment by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on 2021-04-09**:
Might be related to https://answers.ros.org/question/375372/autowareauto-master-branch-source-code-failed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no src/tools/autoware_auto_launch/launch/autoware_auto_visualization.launch.py in the 1.0.0 release ( https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/tree/1.0.0/tools
)

So release 1.0.0 cannot run the AVP demo as presented in the current documentation

It is necessary to use the old version : https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/1.0.0/docs/usage/odd-demos/autonomous-valet-parking.md

---

Originally posted by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) with karma: 108 on 2021-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-04-14**:
We are currently working on a way to provide multiple versions of the docs in [issue #115](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/115). You can track this issue for updates.